# Change the preview image in an SLComposeServiceViewController

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I have created a Safari Share Extension where I get a specific image from the current URL. That part is done but now I am trying to replace the preview image on the SLComposeServiceViewController with the one I scraped from the URL. I cannot seem to find a way to change the preview image that is automatically generated by SLComposeServiceViewController

[image]

How can I change this image?

I've tried looking for at the `inputItems` property of `NSExtenstionContext` but only can see the URL in there.

```
extension NSExtensionContext {
  for item in self.inputItems {
    if let extenstionItem = item as? NSExtensionItem {
      print("attachments = \(extenstionItem.attachments)")
    }
  }
}
```

`attachments = Optional([<NSItemProvider: 0x12d513e70> {types = (
    "public.url"
)}])`

I'm hoping that I can change this image without having to create my own view since this is the only change I need to make to the default.

Even being able to hide the image placed there by default would be helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to accomplish this. You override `loadPreviewView()` in the SLComposeServiceViewController subclass and return the UIImageView (or any view) with the image. To update it during the same runtime, you keep a reference to it in the class.

```
override func loadPreviewView() -> UIView! {        
  imagePreviewView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"))
  return imagePreviewView
}
```